# Include product version in the target directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I'm trying to create a setup project for a product that should be able to install itself alongside its own older version. I have tried to add `[Version]` to the default location of the application folder, but this doesn't seem to work. Namely, when I set this:

`DefaultLocation: [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]-x-[Version]-y`

Setup totally ignores the `Version` variable, and suggests

`C:\Program Files\<company>\<product>-x--y`

as the default location. `[Version]` is set to `<number>.<number>.<number>` in the setup project properties.

What's wrong with me or with VS? How can I add versioning to my default location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Apparently the correct variable to use in this case is `[ProductVersion]` and not `[Version]`.  I have no idea how it is supposed to be known. I have figured it out by looking at the install logs, searching for the word "version", and trying what I've found.